# Autogenerate UUID for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My use case is that I need to have UUID as primary key in one of my DynamoDB tables. I am using @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey for the same and I am able to use UUID. I also understand that the autogenerated key can be retrieved from the entity written to dynamo db just after storing it in dynamo db. But my concern is that is there any clean way to retrieve the auto generated key anywhere in the application or do I need to store the auto generated key in-memory ? Or should I implement secondary indexes to retrieve the autogenerated key ?

Comment: The auto-generated key makes sense only if semantically it fits your use case (for instance if the item's key will be persisted somewhere else such as another table or another system etc.) or if there is a technical reason to use it such as protecting against hot-keys (in which case adding a GSI may make sense). But if neither of those is the case for you then you should consider a more natural key for your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:-** The OP doesn't have information where the use case requires to get data by primary key. I presume the ultimate claim may not be to get the UUID. Rather, it could be to get the item using UUID.

**Some general options are as follows:-**

If you don't know the Hash key which is auto generated UUID,

1) **Scan** the table to get the auto-generated key. Please note that this is a full table scan which would be a costly operation.

2) Yes, **Global Secondary Index** can be used to query the table by different attributes i.e. other than the UUID field defined as Hash key in main table. This is the more efficient option if hash key of the main table is unknown.

3) I am not sure about the full use case. However, if the same HTTP request or process is going to get the data later for the newly inserted UUID, you can keep the UUID in-memory (i.e. using Java collection) to use it later. In this case, in fact you can keep the entire object that was inserted earlier in-memory.